# ndk: linking static library error

Tags: android-ndk

I have compiled(hopefully with success) fftw library. I want to link it to my ndk projects.
I have 2 android.mk files:
 /analysis/fftw3/

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := fftw3

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/libfftw3f.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

#LOCAL_LDFLAGS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/libfftw3f.a
#LOCAL_LDLIBS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/libfftw3f.a


include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

#$(call import-module, fftw3)
```

the main android.mk file in /

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := jni
FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.c)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/**/*.c)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/**/**/*.c)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/**/**/**/*.c)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
#LOCAL_SRC_FILES := analysis/fftw3/lib/libfftw3f.a
#LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/analysis/fftw3/include

#LOCAL_LDFLAGS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/analysis/fftw3/lib/libfftw3f.a
#LOCAL_LDLIBS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/analysis/fftw3/lib/libfftw3f.a
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := analysis/fftw3/fftw3

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/analysis/fftw3/Android.mk
```

I have tried many things (as you can see with the comments..) but what i'm getting is "undefined reference" when i try to call a function from libfftw3f library.
all seem ok.  i don't know what i'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

> LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := analysis/fftw3/fftw3

This line should rather be

> LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := fftw3

Indeed, you must only list the local static libraries, with the same name you specified on the line

> LOCAL_MODULE := fftw3

It should link correctly, given the path you specified for `LOCAL_SRC_FILE` for the lib is correct.